# Simulate “Inner Shadow” for Android VectorDrawable (Vector Drawable)

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, vector, android-vectordrawable

My goal is to create an Android [adaptive icon](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive) using vector drawable (XML) for -anydpi-v26.

- res

  - drawable-anydpi-v26

    - ic_launcher_background.xml
    - ic_launcher_foreground.xml

Apparently, [filter effects such as drop shadows, blurs, and color matrix are **NOT** supported](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#svg-unsupported) by Android Studio's Vector Asset Studio (SVG importer). No `<filter>` `</filter>` elements!

So, do you know any way to **simulate** inner shadow effect inside an SVG file **without** using filter elements (perhaps by gradients and opacity)? Preferably in Inkscape or Affinity Designer.

I insist on Vector Drawable (XML). Transparent PNG is not an option.

[Shapes icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gwdp.png)

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 108 108" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB" id="a" x="-.08" y="-.05" width="1.13" height="1.13">
      <feFlood flood-opacity=".5" flood-color="#000" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="flood" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="out" result="composite1"/>
      <feGaussianBlur in="composite1" stdDeviation="1" result="blur"/>
      <feOffset dx="-1" dy="1" result="offset"/>
      <feComposite in="offset" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="atop" result="composite2"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <path style="fill:#73e8ff" d="M0 0h864v864H0z" transform="scale(.125)"/>
  <g style="filter:url(#a)">
    <path d="m53.63 37 6.66 4.84-2.55 7.82h-8.23l-2.54-7.82L53.63 37Z" style="fill:#29b6f6" transform="translate(-36.72 -23.11) scale(1.47134)"/>
    <path d="M21.66 56.7 25 59.14l-1.66 2.29 2.7.87-1.28 3.92-2.7-.88v2.83h-4.1v-2.83l-2.7.88-1.27-3.92 2.7-.87-1.67-2.3 3.33-2.41L20 59l1.66-2.3Z" style="fill:#29b6f6" transform="rotate(180 38.98 89) scale(1.78662)"/>
    <path d="M46.5 64a6.5 6.5 0 1 1 0 13 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 0-13Zm0 3.25a3.25 3.25 0 1 1 0 6.5 3.25 3.25 0 0 1 0-6.5Z" style="fill:#29b6f6" transform="translate(-7.45 -45.56) scale(1.58452)"/>
    <path d="M71 35.69c1.47-2.1 4.42-2.1 5.9-1.05 1.47 1.05 1.47 3.15 0 5.25-1.04 1.57-3.69 3.15-5.9 4.2-2.21-1.05-4.86-2.63-5.9-4.2-1.47-2.1-1.47-4.2 0-5.25 1.48-1.05 4.43-1.05 5.9 1.05Z" style="fill:#29b6f6" transform="matrix(1.47134 0 0 1.96178 -38.24 -35.06)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You can simulate a dropshadow for a straight line or a circle/ellipse using linear and radial gradients, but you can't do it for the types of complex paths you have.

Comment: Almost a year and still no answer?  I have this question too!